# NCL Draw a map without the sourrounding frame

Tags: mapping, ncl

eI'm working with NCL 6.6.2 under Debian and wan't to create some projection images.  How can i prevent to draw a frame around the map. I cannot find the right Attribute at the moment.

```
;================================================;
;  map1.ncl
;================================================;
begin

  wks  = gsn_open_wks("png","map1")  ; send graphics to PNG file

  res                       = True
  res@gsnFrame              = False  ; <-- This seems not to work because it draw nothing at all.

  res = True;
  res@mpProjection               = "Satellite" ; choose map projection
  res@mpCenterLonF               = 13.         ; choose center lon
  res@mpCenterLatF               = 54.         ; choose center lat
  res@mpSatelliteDistF           = 3.0         ; choose satellite view
  res@mpOutlineOn                = False       ; 
  res@mpGridAndLimbOn        = True
  res@mpDataBaseVersion      = "MediumRes"  

  col = (/ .20, 0.20, 0.30, .8/)
  res@mpLandFillColor        = col
  res@mpOceanFillColor       = "White"
  res@mpInlandWaterFillColor = col

  plot = gsn_csm_map(wks, res)  ; draw satellite proj map
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set `@gsnFrame=False`, `NCL` will not draw temporarily.

How to fix it?

in the end, add:

```
frame(wks)
draw(plot)
```